# docker login to openshift internal docker registry - Gateway Timeout

Tags: openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin, minishift

Running the openshift cluster using minishift in ubuntu OS. minishift IP is "192.168.42.48". I am following the [URL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5VzXvvkiL4) to access the internal docker registry.

After the minishift has started successfully, logged in as administrator using "oc login -u system:admin" then added the cluster-role to user "chak".

```
~/github/cheatsheets$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin chak
cluster role "cluster-admin" added: "chak"
```

Then copied the token for user "chak" and trying to login to docker registry but it has failed with below error. The minishift ip and ip in the error output is different. In the terminal, already logged in as administrator and added a cluster-admin role.

So, I expect docker daemon to login to the openshift cluster ip that is started by the minishift. why is docker daemon trying to login to ip in the error rather than than minishift ip?

I also have http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy set, since i am connected to corporate network.

```
~/github/cheatsheets$ docker login -u chak -p C5u5F1iwA6gl4va1K8OZ01DaRPdMYMnDQklErn2FzjY docker-registry-default.127.0.0.1.nip.io
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
error during connect: Post https://192.168.42.253:2376/v1.39/auth: Gateway Timeout
```

Edit 1:

```
~/github/hashitvault$  docker login -u chak -p Naqp6NScYF7zOcKN41SuYQ045qR9zBN6lfGVnvxhrU docker-registry-default.192.168.42.186.nip.io
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get http://docker-registry-default.192.168.42.186.nip.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

oc internal docker registry route is exposed.
[image]

when hit in browser,reaching the 502 server error. 
[image]

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: check where registry URL pointing to in ${HOME}/.docker/config.json

Comment: The video appears to be slightly obsolete, using `oc cluster up` (v 3.6) and manually creating a route for the internal registry. This is not needed with current Minishift. For accessing Minishift's registry, I recommend following [the documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/openshift/openshift-docker-registry.html) (including [this](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/docker-daemon.html)).

Comment: @ankidaemon - thanks for the response. I had to take time and try this in the fresh minishift instance. today, I tried but seeing the different error which is in edit-1. The oc internal docker registry url is not yet added to the $HOME/.docker/config.json. I believe this will be added only after successful login to registry. I am getting the 502 error when hit from browser. what could be exact issue and where to get the logs for this failure.

Comment: I tried to deploy an vault applicaiton to verify the service and route. I could access the vault without any issues but could not access the docker registry. do I need any authentication and certificates to access the registry.